# CSS Backdrop Filter Not Fully Covering Screen (Only on Chrome)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

On my website I have a div with a bunch of circles behind it that is blurred to give a cool gradient effect. It has been working for a long time, but I tried it today on Chrome and it now doesn't blur all the way down. At the bottom part it's not blurred all the way. It works on iOS chrome and Edge, so I think it's a Chrome related issue. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image: This is what it looks like]

```css
.animated-mesh {
  background-color: var(--mesh-color-bg);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

.animated-mesh::after {
  /* This is the thing that blurs what is behind */
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  backdrop-filter: blur(80px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(80px);
}

.animated-mesh div:nth-child(3) {
  /* css for one of the blurred divs, theyre all the similar */
  height: 65%;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: var(--mesh-color-3);
  right: -20%;
  bottom: -15%;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="animated-mesh">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="mesh-mouse-hover" id="mesh-mouse-hover"></div>
</div>
```

I tried changing `.animated-mesh::after`'s properties, increasing size(no change), changing position type(broke effect), changing blur intensity(no change)

I tried changing `.animated-mesh`'s size and it only increased the size of the backdrop with the same issue

Comment: have you tried making the `::after` fixed instead of absolute? Also, the `bottom: 0; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0` might be more reliable than setting the size